# Как сделать умный фильтр не на странице Каталога? Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

У меня есть страница "Производители" где вывожу список производителя, я хочу по нажатию на производителя выводить товары нужного производителя. Вот только не создавать же мне новый каталог? Если товары указаны в основном каталоге? Вывод работает, вот только при включении поддержки ЧПУ у меня всё ломается.
Путь такой - жму на производителя: /manufacturers/?SECTION_ID=338
Настройки ЧПУ
Раздел #SECTION_CODE_PATH#/
Детальная информация #SECTION_ID#/#ELEMENT_ID#/
URL фильтра #SECTION_ID#/filter/#SMART_FILTER_PATH#/apply/
С битриксом у меня плохо, но задачу сделать надо.

Comment: Простейший способ - добавить в умный фильтр фильтрацию по производителю. Затем посмотреть, какой адрес формирует умный фильтр. И переходить со списка призводителей на соответствующий адрес, а не на  /manufacturers/?SECTION_ID=338.